# I'm not able to get access $wpdb in my php file in wordpress

Tags: php, plugin-development

```
//include_once "WP-ROOT-PATH/wp-config.php";
//include_once "../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php";
//define( 'BLOCK_LOAD', true );
//require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wordpress/wp-config.php' );
//require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
//$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
 //i tried all these method to access wp files but gives error//////
class repository{

function save($name,$email,$address1,$address2,$code)
{

    global $wpdb;////this variable is null now 
    $wp_Table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'conssv12frm';
    $status = $wpdb->insert( 
                        $wp_Table_name, 
                        array( 
                            "name" => $name, 
                            "email" => $email, 
                            "address1"=> $address1,
                            "address2"=> $address2,
                            "code"=> $code
                        ), 
                        array( 
                            '%s', 
                            '%s',
                            '%s', 
                            '%s',
                            '%d'
                        ) 
                    );


     $message = $status?"Data has been inserted":"Server Error";
     return new response($status,null,null,$message);

}
}
```

Here `$wpdp` returns null. I have searched everywhere and also I include `wp-config.php` and `wp-include/wp-admin.php`, to access `$wpdb` variable but it gives error that file didn't found.

Comment: Have you completely read the outdated article you've copied the code from? It says "WordPress 3.4 broke this method, but I have a new method."

Comment: LOL @MaxYudin...

Comment: it my code ...i have'nt copied if u have solution then help ....thanx@MaxYudin

Comment: I suppose you are trying to access WordPress from the outside script. This should be written in the question. [wp-load.php](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp-load.php?sort=votes)

Comment: i'm new to wordpress please help me out rather then making fun ...

Comment: i have made a plugin in dat iam filling my form and submiting to this php file wt some how i dont know why $wpdb is not working .....as i have made it global for simple access

Comment: Can you specify file path of this file you've posted?

Comment: wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ssvcontactform/form_submition.php

Comment: there are gazillions tutorials on how to properly write ajax in wordpress, and specifically on this site it was said tenths of times (if not more) that you should never directly access php files in you plugin or theme folders

Answer (score 0):

Since this is in your plugins, accessing global should work unless you're calling the file externally.

Anyway since it's not working, you'll have to include `wp-config.php`. Make sure your file path is proper. Also if it doesn't work, put include statement inside your `save` function.

Comment: yes that's the issue .it should work with simple globel $wpdb ..........and if iam including this wp-config.php ...my form is submiting but when iam going backto dashboard there its giving error fail to open stream wp-config

Comment: ok ill try that inside my function..

Comment: If it's giving failed to open error, your path might be wrong

Comment: it will help if you spell `global` correctly - details matter